# error in parsing JSON in java

Tags: java

I have a response from API that generates authorization token with some other attributes, I'm trying to extract the value of the token from the response which looks like below

```
 {"access_token":"tokenvalue","scope":"somevalue","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":value}
```

i tried JSON parse like below:

```
 Myclass response = template.postForObject(url, requestEntity,  Myclas.class);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(response);
        String product = (String) jsonObject.get("access_token");
            token = response;
        }
```

Recieved error:

```
parse( ) 
in JSONParser cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: The json response is an invalid json. did u mask the expires_in or that's how is it?

Comment: check this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/

Comment: @KarthikR this is the response: {"access_token":"tokenvalue","scope":"somevalue","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":1235}

Answer (score 1):

With the line:

```
String product = (String) jsonObject.get("access_token");
```

You are trying to get a property called "access_token".

However if you look at your json you will see that there is no property called "access_token".

Perhaps you meant:

```
String product = (String) jsonObject.get("token");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said by Neng Liu before me, this JSON could be incorrect:

*{"token":"tokenvalue","scope":"somevalue","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":* **value** *}*

Another thing is that JSONObject can receive the JSON format in its constructor  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(***response***) in your case and then use obj.get("***your filed***")

Comment: JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("{\"access_token\":\"token\", \"scope\":value, \"token_type\":Bearer, \"expires_in\":97822}");
            System.out.println("access_token=" +  json.get("access_token"));

Got this error: JSONParser() in JSONParser cannot be applied to:....i'm using jdk.nashorn

Comment: Sorry, but scope variable is a string?

Comment: @hellomluca, yes it's a string :)

Comment: So this json file is uncorrect. It must be like this: "{\"access_token\":\"token\", \"scope\": " value " , \"token_type\":Bearer, \"expires_in\":97822}"